# Connect SharpDevelop to SQL Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I am used to develop everything in VS. But since I have tried to download VS many times and crashed (I used to rightclick properties setting and make connection string), I started using another IDE - SharpDevelop.

Can anyone explain how to make connection string from my solution in SharpDevelop to connect to SQL Server database?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask , how to repair your Vs-installation, rather than changing to a new IDE?

Comment: @Nikolaus believe me i have tried everything related to repair VS,i even reinstall the whole windows OS for this. But nothing fixed my problem.

Comment: Which version of VS do/did you use?